# Continuous Speech Recognition using Microsoft Cognitive Speech + Websocket - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to build a **continuous speech recognition** from **microphone** using the **Microsoft Cognitive Speech** for **Xamarin Android**. I don't think there is library for Xamarin so I modified the **"Xamarin.Cognitive.BingSpeech**" library a little bit (the endpoint, etc) to get it work. I have some problem

I want to connect to the microsoft web socket by following tutorial from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol.

I tried sending **HTTPREQUEST** using basic **HttpClient** and got the 101 switch protocol result (I guess I succeed this part?).

UPDATE : My HTTP Request is :

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

var request = new HttpWebRequest(uriBuilder.Uri);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(Bearer, AuthClient.Token).ToString());
request.Accept=MimeTypes.Json;
request.Host = SpeechEndpoint.Host;
request.Connection = "Upgrade";
request.Headers.Add("Upgrade", "Websocket");
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Method = "GET";
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.Date = DateTime.Now;
request.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.CacheIfAvailable);
request.Headers.Add("Sec-WebSocket-Key", "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==");
request.Headers.Add("Sec-WebSocket-Version", "13");
request.Headers.Add("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol", "chat, superchat");
request.Headers.Add("X-ConnectionId",xConnectionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper());
```

After making a HTTPRequest, I am trying to connect to the websocket,
but I always get "Unable to connect to remote server" without any error code or anything. (wss://xxxxxxxx).

```
Uri wsuri = new Uri(AppConfig.BINGWSSURI);
await _socketclient.ConnectAsync(wsuri, CancellationToken.None);
Log.Info("WSOCKETFINISH", _socketclient.State.ToString());
```

The second thing I want to achieve is to stream the audio from microphone to the websocket using binary message, so I have to

1. Record from Microphone (I am using **Plugin.AudioRecorder**)
2. Cut it into small chunk pieces
3. Stream the small pieces asynchronously using the websocket

What I want to achieve : Speech to Text using Microphone with Microsoft Cognitive Speech, dictation mode, so I need partial result instead of waiting the recording to be completed.

Comment: Just wanna share that the token server for Cognitive Speech are different from Bing Speech.
Bing : https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken,   
 Cognitive Speech : https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to convert the speech to text.
 Since the [Xamarin.Cognitive.BingSpeech](https://github.com/NateRickard/Xamarin.Cognitive.BingSpeech#platform-configuration) needs you to record the speech and send them as file or stream to the server. I think you could try to use [Android speech](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/speech). And it could also convert text to speech. [Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/PlatformFeatures/SpeechToText/) is an example.

If you want to use Xamarin.Cognitive.BingSpeech, you could use [Audio Recorder plugin](https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder) to record the speech and use `BingSpeechApiClient` to send to server. For example:

```
BingSpeechApiClient bingSpeechClient = new BingSpeechApiClient ("My Bing Speech API Subscription Key");
var audioFile = "/a/path/to/my/audio/file/in/WAV/format.wav";
var simpleResult = await bingSpeechClient.SpeechToTextSimple (audioFile);
Or
var simpleResult = await bingSpeechClient.SpeechToTextSimple (stream, <sample rate>, <audio record Task>);
```

[Here](https://github.com/NateRickard/Xamarin.Cognitive.BingSpeech/tree/master/Sample) is the example for Xamarin.Cognitive.BingSpeech.

**Update:**

> I always get "Unable to connect to remote server" without any error code or anything.

You are missing something value in header.

1. X-ConnectionId
   You need to generate a UUID and add it to the header. For example: `client.Options.SetRequestHeader("X-ConnectionId", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());`
2. Authorization
    You need post your subscription key to  https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken. You could use Postman to do this. Then add the return value in the header.

   client.Options.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q....uW72PAOBRcUvqY");

[image]

> so I need partial result instead of waiting the recording to be completed

You could use the `GetAudioFileStream()` method.For example:

```
    var audioRecordTask = await recorder.StartRecording();
    using (var stream = recorder.GetAudioFileStream ())
    {
        //this will get the recording audio data as it continues to record
    }
```

**Update2:**
The websoket part code:

```
    var client = new ClientWebSocket();
    client.Options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.Options.SetRequestHeader("X-ConnectionId", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    client.Options.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL....16pbFPOWT3VHXot8");
    var a = client.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/Dictation/cognitiveservices/v1"), CancellationToken.None);
    a.Wait();
```

**Note**: Keep your Authorization's value up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I already followed the Xamarin.Cognitive.BingSpeech, but my problem is I want to stream the audio using the websockets while recording instead of waiting the recorder to finish and then process.

Comment: @VincentElbertBudiman I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thank you again for your response @Billy, I already got  the 101 switch protocol result from the http request, but the "Unable to connect to remote server " error is on the 
`await _socketclient.ConnectAsync(uriBuilder.Uri, CancellationToken.None); `.

Comment: @VincentElbertBudiman Yes, I know this. I have reproduced this error. And I fixed it by adding the X-ConnectionId and  Authorization in `ClientWebSocket` header. Are you using the `ClientWebSocket`?

Comment: Ah yes thank you, I didn't notice any documentation on putting the Authorization and X-ConnectionId on 'ClientWebSocket' anywhere (or is it a default? Since it's my first time dealing with websocket).